# Autocomplete theorem environments not auto-completing

Tags: auto-completion

I am using TexStudio, and this question might be more about TexStudio than about LaTeX but I will ask here anyway.  I am writing a long math paper which I have trimmed down to the bare essentials in the code below.  When I start to write
`\begin{th' TexStudio will offer me autocomplete on completing the theorem environment.  After typing just the above, autocomplete allows me to push enter and it then TexStudio auto-completes as

```
\begin{thm}
    content...
\end{thm}
```

It used to do the same thing for the proof environment when I would begin
`\begin{pro' and then I could push enter to auto-complete

```
\begin{proof}
    content...
\end{proof}
```

but it suddenly doesn't do that any more.  Can any of you please tell me ho to get the auto-complete reactivated for the the proof environment?  I probably had an update in TexStudio or something.  I don't recall when the proof environment auto-complete stopped working.  Thanks!

```
\documentclass[twoside,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\S \thesection}{1em}{} \titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large\bfseries\filcenter}{\S \thesubsection}{1em}{}

\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks, thref]{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theoremsymbol{\textleaf}
\newtheorem*{proof}{\textsf{\underline{Proof.}}}[subsection]

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{thm}
    content...
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
    content...
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you may define newtheorem in an imported file.

TXS will recognize the command only if the file defining the commands is loaded (Note: There is an option Configure... -> Editor -> Automatically load included files)

see [this FAQ](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#why-does-a-command-not-show-up-in-the-completion)

This works for me.

Also, check if you have checked amsthm.cwl and amsmath.cwl in Configure->Completion